# Linq to objects - Search collection with value from other collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections, linq-to-objects

I've tried to search SO for solutions and questions that could be similar to my case.

I got 2 collections of objects:

```
public class BRSDocument
{
    public string IdentifierValue { get; set;}
}

public class BRSMetadata
{
    public string Value { get; set;}
}
```

I fill the list from my datalayer:

```
List<BRSDocument> colBRSDocuments = Common.Instance.GetBRSDocuments();
List<BRSMetadata> colBRSMetadata = Common.Instance.GetMessageBRSMetadata();
```

I now want to find that one object in colBRSDocuments where x.IdentifierValue is equal to the one object in colBRSMetadata y.Value. I just need to find the BRSDocument that matches a value from the BRSMetadata objects.

I used a ordinary foreach loop and a simple linq search to find the data and break when the value is found. I'm wondering if the search can be done completely with linq?

```
foreach (var item in colBRSMetadata)
{
    BRSDocument res = colBRSDocuments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdentifierValue == item.Value);

    if (res != null)
    {
        //Do work
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope that some of you guys can push me in the right direction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do a join?

```
var docs = from d in colBRSDocuments
           join m in colBRSMetadata on d.IdentiferValue equals m.Value
           select d;
```

If there's only meant to be one then you can do:

```
var doc = docs.Single(); // will throw if there is not exactly one element
```

---

If you want to return both objects, then you can do the following:

```
var docsAndData = from d in colBRSDocuments
                  join m in colBRSMetadata on d.IdentiferValue equals m.Value
                  select new
                  {
                      Doc = d,
                      Data = m
                  };
```

then you can access like:

```
foreach (var dd in docsAndData)
{
    // dd.Doc
    // dd.Data
}
```

Comment: I will try that - didn't know that you could do a join on collections that are not related :)

Comment: Cool. Report back once you've given it a go!

Comment: This solution provides the needed result and is also very readable for the programmer. Nice job!

Comment: Just a quick question: Is it possible to return both objects? The BRSDocument and the BRSMetadata object that was used to find the BRSDocument?

Comment: -> I just came to the same solution with the select new and assigning the objects! Great to know I'm not way of with my thinking! Once againg - thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq ? 
Something like this should do the job :

```
foreach (var res in colBRSMetadata.Select(item => colBRSDocuments.FirstOrDefault(x =>      x.IdentifierValue == item.Value)).Where(res => res != null))
        {
            //Do work
            break;
        }
```

If you are just interested by the first item, then the code would be :

```
var brsDocument = colBRSMetadata.Select(item => colBRSDocuments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdentifierValue == item.Value)).FirstOrDefault(res => res != null);
        if (brsDocument != null)
            //Do Stuff
```

Comment: I did try this solution and the result was as expected - it also found the object i needed. I was trying to avoid the foreach syntax - so the solution provided by dav_i seems to fit my needs best. Thanks for you input - it might come in handy some other time :)

Comment: I will try that solution later today! :)